# how to install python-spidermonkey on windows

Tags: python

I'm writing some scripts with python mechanize. One of problems I'm having is it is really hard to find which support javascript supported web client scraping or crawler. I found some such as `python-spidermonkey` and `pykhtml`, but most are only supported on Linux.

I want to make my python script with exe file, so definitely I have to install on windows platform.

My question is, is there any method to install `python-spidermonkey` or `pykhtml` on Windows?

Answer (score -1):

Both these links: http://code.google.com/p/python-spidermonkey/issues/detail?id=5 and http://www.ohloh.net/p/python-spidermonkey say that Spedermonkey is not supported for Windows... yet.

As far as I can tell, PyKHTML is not out for Windows yet, but "support for Windows/Mac should appear in the next few months." (http://paul.giannaros.org/pykhtml/)

Comment: hello, thanks for your reply, yes as already i was said,it not support windows platform, too sad thing. are there any method to make script on linux platform and make it output script to work with on windows platform? such as make it work with py2exe

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're looking for, but if you do use py2exe, then you should be able to run the compiled exe on Windows despite having developed the code on Linux. This is because py2exe compiles all the required modules into DLLs which get referenced to the exe derived from your code. However, I'm not sure whether your code's dependency on spidermonkey or PyKHTML, will be ported over properly. All I can suggest is that you give it a try. It will take very little of your time, and will conclusively either work or fail. Try it out, and please let me know how it goes. Cheers

Comment: Hello, inspectorG4dget :)
Yes,i want to try it,but lack of my knowledge i even don't know how to start ..actually i want to say..im novice for programming 
if anyone can try it instead of me ...maybe it fantastic thing :)

Comment: py2exe is actually EXTREMELY straightforward. I remember freaking out the first time I saw the how-to page, but then I realized I was freaking out over a lot of output that I really didn't have to care about. I would love to give this a try, but with midterms etc right now, I wouldn't get around to it for quite some time. I would recommend that you go to: http://www.py2exe.org/ and try it yourself first. At the very least, you would have experienced something new. Relying on someone else to do an experiment for you usually takes a lot longer.

Comment: py2exe is straightforward, but it won't help you if your Python libraries (PyKHTML or python-spidermonkey) can't be built for Windows (which they currently can't).