# How to execute Javascript from Python on Windows?

Tags: javascript, python

how can I execute Javascript from Python on Windows?

I want to get python-spidermonkey functionality. Just like this:

```
>>> class Foo:
...   def hello(self):
...     print "Hello, Javascript world!"
>>> cx.bind_class(Foo, bind_constructor=True)
>>> cx.eval_script("var f = new Foo(); f.hello();")
Hello, Javascript world!
```

**I can't use python-spidermonkey, because it doesn't work in [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727157/how-to-install-python-spidermonkey-on-windows)**

Comment: What?  Javascript is part of a web page download?  What do you mean "javascript from Python"?  What are you doing?

Comment: If you want to get python-spidermonkey functionality, why don't you use python-spidermonkey? (http://code.google.com/p/python-spidermonkey/)

Answer (score 4):

How about pyv8: http://code.google.com/p/pyv8/

Answer (score 1):

You could call [SpiderMonkey](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-spidermonkey).